# i-nex package throws an error with any apt-get command

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install some packages and got an error related to i-nex package.

```
# apt-get install yum
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
yum is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bsdtar kdebase-runtime libsdl-ttf2.0-0 linux-headers-3.13.0-24
  linux-headers-3.13.0-24-lowlatency linux-image-3.13.0-24-lowlatency
  ruby-childprocess ruby-erubis ruby-ffi ruby-i18n ruby-log4r ruby-net-scp
  ruby-net-ssh
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up i-nex (7.4.0+bzr887+20150112~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package i-nex (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 i-nex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I reinstall it or solve this problem?

Comment: installing yum... probably a bad idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post-installation script contains the following line which fails with the return code 6.

```
curl --silent https://i-nex.pl/?downloadcount=1 > /dev/null 1>&1
```

You can test this in a terminal

```
curl --silent https://i-nex.pl/\?downloadcount\=1 > /dev/null 1>&1; echo $?
```

---

Therefore open the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/i-nex.postinst`

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/i-nex.postinst
```

and remove the line.

After that remove the package

```
sudo apt-get remove i-nex
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Into terminal type:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/i-nex.postinst
   ```
2. Add `exit 0` at end of file and save it.
3. To finish, run `sudo apt-get -f install` to complete the installation.

Reference: [Launchpad bug 1503053](https://bugs.launchpad.net/i-nex/+bug/1503053)

Comment: A rather crude way to solve an error :) but maybe this one should never have given an error anyway.